# How to prove ADM mass is independent of the foliation considered?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, mass, adm-formalism

ADM mass for an asymptotically-flat
spacetime can be defined as (Poisson, Eric. A relativist's toolkit. p.147):

$$M=-\frac{1}{8 \pi} \lim _{S_t \rightarrow \infty} \oint_{S_t}\left(k-k_0\right) \sqrt{\sigma} \mathrm{d}^2 \theta,$$
where $S_t$ is a is a two-sphere at spatial infinity.

My question is the following: this definition apparently depends on the spatial foliation considered ($S_t$ lives in these spatial hyperplanes). How can be proven that it is in fact independent?

Comment: Try applying generalized Stokes theorem along with the fact that $\partial S_t=\emptyset $